# How to send order cancel to customer

Tags: magento-1.9, email, email-templates

I am using **Magento 1.9** in my website. I try to **send order cancel mail** to **customer** but it's not working i came across may solution but none of the thing is not working can you please any one **suggest for solution** on this?

Answer (score 0):

A method you can use is the Event Observer sales_order_save_commit_after
What will offer the ability to send certain emails depending on what just happened.
This will be inspected on every order save, so its not too efficient.